# centos install php-odbc dependicies

Tags: centos6, unixodbc

I run "yum install php-odbc" command in centos6.x64
and reponse messages in terminal:

```
yum install php-odbc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo.boun.edu.tr
 * epel: mirror.fraunhofer.de
 * extras: mirror.alastyr.com
 * updates: repo.boun.edu.tr
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-odbc.x86_64 0:5.3.3-46.el6_6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6 for package: php-odbc-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-odbc-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Installed: php-common-5.6.13-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (installed)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.13-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
           Available: php54w-common-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-2.w6
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.30-2.w6
           Available: php56w-common-5.6.14-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.14-2.w6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Its so obvious I need to install these packages, but how can I.. and I actually ask for generic solution for this kind of issue. How can I install all dependencies packages with current install.

EDITED: "php -v" response:
[image]

Comment: What does `php -v` tell you when executed from a shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Installed: php-common-5.6.13-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (installed)
```

Tells me that you're probably running PHP 5.6 installed from the [remi repository](http://rpms.remirepo.net/).

Have a look in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and see if you've got any `.repo` files with names beginning with `remi`. In particular, `remi.repo`.

If you have, try and install using:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi --enablerepo=remi-php56 install php-odbc
```

Comment: yes I have, this the response from that command : "No such command php-odbc. Please try..."

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ - sorry, missed the `install` command from that yum line...try it again

Comment: @MehmetYenerYILMAZ - fabby, glad I could help.

Comment: Probably simpler to enabled "remi-php56" permanently to avoid more issues (the repo only contains php 5.6 and extensions) using: yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56  (only need "remi-safe" which is enabled by default)

Comment: @RemiCollet - you're probably right. I'll add to answer if you don't mind me doing so. Are you "The Remi"? :)

Comment: Of course, you can edit your anser, and yes, I'm the maintainer of "remi" repository.